# .NET unit testing framework without the use of attributes

Tags: .net, nunit, xunit

Does any of the more common unit testing frameworks (MSUnit, NUnit, xUnit) support a mechanism where I can write code that returns the list of test methods instead of them being collected automatically based on attributes?

I would like to write a single method that either reads the tests from an external data source or use reflection with my own logic to find the test methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own test runner for that matter.
All it takes is to filter methods from an assembly or some other source which plan to write anyway. Then run these methods in a try catch block.

You can also consider the following filtering solutions with NUnit (I'm not sure about the other frameworks.)

a) Split your tests to categories and even write your own custom category attributes as explained in the following discussion: [Are Custom Filters in NUnit Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272803/are-custom-filters-in-nunit-possible)

b) Use the filtering mechanism thought it's XML and not code: https://github.com/nunit/dev/wiki/Test-Filters.